# reCAPTCHA invisible without callback function

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I have a form that's handled with an event listener and that doesn't play well with recaptcha's callback function.

Inside the form:

**Form**

```
<form class="myform>
...
<button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-callback='onSubmit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now it relies on function `onSubmit` to handle to get the token as below.

**reCaptcha callback and token handler**

```
var onSubmit = function(token) {
  console.log('token');
};
```

However I want to get the token in my form handler below. `onSubmit` and eventlistener below are fired at the same time but can't interchange the token.

**My form handler where I want the token**

```
$('form.myform').submit(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var token = ''; // how do I get the token?
    submitForm(form, token); // token is not defined here but I want it to be

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should trigger the form submit:

```
var onSubmit = function(token) {
    $( "form.myform" ).submit();
};
```

Your form submit handler function:

```
$('form.myform').submit(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var token = grecaptcha.getResponse(); 
    submitForm(form, token);

});
```